# Duda sobre la clausura en Javascript

Tags: javascript

muy buenas y gracias de antemano por leer esto.

Dado un código como este:

```
function uno(){
    function dos(){
        alert('no debería de aparecer')
    }
    return dos;
}
var res = uno();
res()
```

¿no debería devolver el objeto **función dos** en vez mostrar la alerta debido a que  **uno()** devuleve el objeto y no la llamada (dos())?

Esto no me deja dormir.
Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Pero tu variable `res` almacena la funcion `uno()` y la función uno retorna `dos`que es la otra función donde muestra el `alert`... que deseas hacer?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Deseo sobretodo comprender. Tendría más sentido si devolviese la llamada así: return dos(). Porque si no?. ¿como lo haría si quisiera devolver el objeto función dos. No deseo saber como sino porque ?? jeje

Answer (score 0):

JS es muy permisivo te deja hacer casi cualquier cosa...

Lo primero en JS cualquier cosa que se inicialice hereda de object así que las funciones son objetos. Por otro lado tu puedes guardar cualquier cosa en variables incluso funciones. (al usar () las invocas).

De haber retornado dos() en vez de dos, hubieses conseguido un error en consola aunque el alert se te mostraría. Pero como la función uno ya no devuelve una función si no el resultado de dos y este no tiene un return, res será undefined y al intentar ejecutar undefined te dará un error en consola.

Espero que te haya aclarado algo sino no dudes en preguntar

Comment: Gracias pero sigo con lo mismo. Y cambio el código para que no se confunda la duda.
    'function uno(){
        function dos(){
            alert('no debería de aparecer');
            return 'hola';
        }
        return dos;
    }
    var res = uno();
    res()'

La cuestión es que no debería devolver ni ejecutar la función dos() porque estoy pidiendo que retorne el objeto función dos y no estoy pidiendo que la ejecute.Estoy pidiendo que ejecute función uno para que retorne el objeto función dos

Comment: Perdón por el formato, intento cambiarlo pero no puedo

Comment: Claro que va ejecutar la función dos. Cuando haces ** var res = uno() ** la variables res apunta a la función dos si lo printeas te mostrará la función y luego cuando haces ** res() ** la estas ejecutando...

Comment: Bueno si es como dices si . Es decir si la variable apunta a la función dos si. Pero entonces como harias si quisieras que **uno()** devolviera el **objeto funcion dos()**?? Es decir, no que la llame sino que la devuelva.

Comment: Es más, ¿y si la sentencia return estuviese condicionada como iba el compilador a saber donde apuntar?. Francamente creo que esto es así a posta por motivos de seguridad. Intuyo.

Answer (score 0):

Sé que es una pregunta con algo de tiempo pero me pareció curioso, y tal vez le pueda servir de referencia a alguien. La función `uno()` en efecto devuelve la definición de la función `dos()`, sin embargo al hacer la invocación de `res()` (poner los paréntesis `()` como menciona @ChaosPatterm) lo que en realidad está pasando es que llamas a la defición de la función `dos()` o lo que es lo mismo, la ejecutas.

```js
function uno() {
  // INICIO >
  function dos() {
    alert('no debería de aparecer');
  }
  // < FIN

  return dos; // Retornas lo que hay entre INICIO y FIN
}

const res = uno();         // Al invocar a la función, el resultado de res es la
                           // definición de dos()

console.log(uno);          // Definición de uno()
console.log(typeof uno);   // function
console.log(uno());        // Definición de dos()
console.log(typeof uno()); // function

console.log(res);          // Definición de dos()
console.log(typeof res);   // function

res();                     // Aquí invocas a la función dos() puesto que el valor
                           // de res es la definición de dos()
```

Básicamente, es como si tu código fuera igual a esto:

```js
const res = function dos() {
  alert('no debería de aparecer');
}

console.log(res);
console.log(typeof res);
```

En el momento en que tu colocas los paréntesis `()` estás llamando -ejecutando- a la función, es por eso que el alert es visible. Si no los pones, observarás que no se muestra y si haces un `console.log()` notarás que el contenido de `res` es la definición de `dos()`.